# How to change all values/Keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I dont know how to descibe it properly but this is what I want to achieve:

```
import yaml
list = {"test1":1,"test2":2,"test3":3}
print(yaml.dump(list, sort_keys=False, default_flow_style=False))

#Output
# test1: 1
# test2: 2
# test3: 3

# Update somehow

print(yaml.dump(list, sort_keys=False, default_flow_style=False))

#Output
# <@test1>: 1
# <@test2>: 2
# <@test3>: 3
```

Comment: You need to show what you have tried and the errors (or incorrect results) that occurred. Dictionary keys are immutable, so in general you have to insert new keys.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you write code that takes one of the keys as input, and determines the new key value? Can you write code that takes a key and a value, and updates a dict with them? Can you write code that loops over the key-value pairs of a dictionary? Can you see how those pieces would fit together to solve the problem? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: (P.S. Python is perfectly capable of displaying dicts with `print`; it isn't necessary to bring in a third-party library to format them. Also, `list` is a terrible name for a variable that stores a dict.)

Comment: "I dont know how to descibe it properly" This is an important skill to develop as a programmer. It is only possible to write code to solve problems, when those problems are **understood**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a comprehension to transform your keys:

```
# list is not a list but a dict and don't use builtin names
data = {"test1":1,"test2":2,"test3":3}

# transform your keys
data = {f'<@{k}>': v for k, v in data.items()}

# export your data as usual
print(yaml.dump(data, sort_keys=False, default_flow_style=False)
```

Output:

```
<@test1>: 1
<@test2>: 2
<@test3>: 3
```